# how to use showDate method to display date -Android studio and how to import TextView package in studio

Tags: android

how to use `showDate` method to display date
 Android studio and how to import TextView package in studio

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar calendar;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    month = Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDate(year, month + 1, day);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for how use showDate you can show this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdaHgQz_X4U) i think this help you
and set this line
`import android.widget.TextView;`
 under your  package name